# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named error occurs for the directory

Tags: python, pytest

I have this script `test_first.py`

```
from chatbot.lili.lili_api import lili_bot_api

def test_check_url
    x_url = XUrl("https://liliexample.com/")
    is_valid_url = True
    assert is_valid_url
```

my file struture is like this

```
chatbotapp/chatbot/lili/lili_api.py
chatbotapp/tests/first_test.py
chatbotapp/   (current directory)
```

then, I use command pytest `test/test_first.py` in chatbotapp `directroy`

```
chatbotapp# pytest tests/test_firslt.py

.
.
from chatbot.lili.lili_api import lili_bot_api
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatbot'
```

I guess this is because maybe pytest can not find the chatbot directory, however where am I wrong?

Comment: When running tests with pytest, the working directory is added to the Python path by default but it might not include the parent directories of your project's modules.

You can try adding the project's root directory (which contains the "chatbot" directory) to the Python path before running the tests.